# VUE: Com recuperar uma variável do array filtrando pelo valor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Boa tarde, estou precisando recuperar a variável `name` desse array de objetos, quando eu filtrar pelo `id`, quando eu digitar por exemplo o `id` 1, retornar "Sólido"

```
full_category_list: [
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Sólido',
        parent : 0,
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Líquido',
        parent : 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) que calculará qual a categoria selecionada.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: null,
        full_category_list: [
            {
                id: 1, 
                name: 'Sólido',
                parent : 0
            },
            {
                id: 2, 
                name: 'Líquido',
                parent : 0
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        selected_category: function() {
            var category = this.full_category_list.find(cat => cat.id == this.selected);
            return category ? category.name : "Nenhum selecionado";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="selected">
  <div>{{ selected_category }}</div>
</div>
```